# Dirac equation: four-derivative spinor

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

I am confused where the four-derivative acts on.

$$
(i\gamma^\mu \partial^\mu-m)\psi=0
$$

I thought that the derivative will act on the spinor. But is that wrong? What is the relation of it with the gamma matrix?
Similary,
I get that when $ \partial^\mu \psi $ the derivative acts on the $\psi$. 
If There's adjoint of the $\psi$, is it written as $\bar{\psi} \partial^\mu  $ ?
I am asking because I don't really get to which $\psi$ the $\partial^mu$ is acting on when
$$
\bar{\psi}(\gamma^\mu \partial^\mu\psi) + (\bar{\psi}\partial^\mu\gamma^\mu)\psi
$$

Comment: $(i\gamma^\mu \partial^\mu-m)\psi=0$ means $i\gamma^\mu \partial^\mu\psi-m\psi=0$ so, yes, the derivative acts on the spinor $\psi$.

Comment: And in even more confusing notation is the adjoint dirac formula $\bar{\psi}(i \gamma_{\mu} \partial^{\mu} + m)=0$, but that is also to be understood in the same manner as what md2perpe states.